# Delayed bag compensation rights. For flight inside europe

Tags: luggage, europe, compensation, passenger-rights, wizz-air

On a flight with Wizzair (low cost european airline). Flight inside european union. The bag is missing now for around 14 days.

The company emailed me. That as my bag is delayed. I can send them invoices of essential items I need to buy. And they will refund me 50% of invoiced amount

Are they allowed to refund only 50% if invoiced items. Or Am I entitled to higher/100%? And is there a definition of what would be considered- not essential and thus not refunded?

Comment: Magic words “Montreal Convention”. No, they are not allowed to repay only 50%, but you need to act reasonably, and there is a hard limit of about $1700 (total). See https://www.forbes.com/advisor/credit-cards/travel-rewards/montreal-convention-luggage/

Comment: Why 50%? You get new things (so not used one), so you get extra lifetime. Arguing with airline will be difficult. Check your country aviation authority, and check if they have some FAQ or cheat-sheet which they assert different values and way to calculate it. Else you will lose time (and so money)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi the passenger didn't ask to be put in the position where they have to buy new things - the airline caused that. The passenger should not be out-of-pocket due to the airline's fault.

Comment: @brhans: but it is how insurance works. You can argue it is not ethics, but at the end, if the airline pay it with the same weight in gold, it just mean all tickets will be more expensive (for sure airlines will put all costs on travelers, not on own money).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi - But this is not a case of insurance (which is something the passenger would take out & pay for), this is a case of the airline's liability. The airline is responsible to "make you whole", such that you're in no worse position than you were before they lost your luggage. If I go on a vacation, and I pack the clothing & personal items I think I'll need (things which I already own and have paid for), I shouldn't be made to pay extra to replace these things to be able to enjoy my vacation to the same degree as if the airline had not lost my luggage.

Comment: @brhans: I do not not what to answer. We are not in ideal world, and I see traveling as continuous problem solving. it is known that baggage may be lost, and so most travel guides recommend you to keep essential items on cabin luggage. I agree that it is not ideal, but it is so (and I do not like it too). In any case very often it is not airline fault, but some airports and some airport handlers (outside control of airline). As sad solace: you will remember this holidays for long time.